# Is there a way to query for an integer value or NULL without using OR?

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to query for a (list of) values or NULL but not use OR. The reasoning behind trying to not use OR is, that I need to use an index on that field to speed up a query.

A simple example to illustrate my question:

```
CREATE TABLE fruits
(
  name text,
  quantity integer
);
```

(The real table has lots of additional integer columns.)

The query that I'm not happy with is

```
SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE quantity IN (1,2,3,4) OR quantity IS NULL;
```

The query I'm hoping for would be something like

```
SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE quantity MAGIC (1,2,3,4,NULL);
```

I'm using Postgresql 9.1.

As far as I can tell from the docs (e.g. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-comparisons.html) and tests there is no way to do this. But I'm hoping one of you has some magic insight.

Comment: In T-SQL you can use ISNULL(Field, Default) not sure about postgre

Comment: Does the OR produce an inferior query plan?

Comment: @gareththegeek: it's postgres, not postgre

Comment: If you really wanted (I don't think it's worth the effort) you could create a simple SQL function that wraps `IS DISTINCT FROM`, `CREATE OPERATOR =? AS` an operator `=?` based on it, and then use `=? ANY (ARRAY[1,2,3,4,NULL])` . But really, why, just using `OR` or `CASE` or `COALESCE` is much saner.

Comment: @Henning: Yes, inferior in the sense, that it can not use a multi column index, which would greatly speed up my (more complex) query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test table with 100k rows:

```
create table fruits (name text, quantity integer);
insert into fruits (name, quantity)
select left(md5(i::text), 6), i
from generate_series(1, 10000) s(i);
```

With plain index on quantity:

```
create index fruits_index on fruits(quantity);
analyze fruits;
```

The query with `or`:

```
explain analyze
SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE quantity IN (1,2,3,4) OR quantity IS NULL;
                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                         
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on fruits  (cost=21.29..34.12 rows=4 width=11) (actual time=0.032..0.032 rows=4 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((quantity = ANY ('{1,2,3,4}'::integer[])) OR (quantity IS NULL))
   ->  BitmapOr  (cost=21.29..21.29 rows=4 width=0) (actual time=0.025..0.025 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on fruits_index  (cost=0.00..17.03 rows=4 width=0) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=4 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (quantity = ANY ('{1,2,3,4}'::integer[]))
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on fruits_index  (cost=0.00..4.26 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (quantity IS NULL)
 Total runtime: 0.089 ms
```

Without `or`:

```
explain analyze
SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE quantity IN (1,2,3,4);
                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                       
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using fruits_index on fruits  (cost=0.00..21.07 rows=4 width=11) (actual time=0.026..0.038 rows=4 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (quantity = ANY ('{1,2,3,4}'::integer[]))
 Total runtime: 0.085 ms
```

The coalesce version proposed by wildplasser leads to a sequential scan:

```
explain analyze
SELECT * 
FROM fruits
WHERE COALESCE(quantity, -1) IN (-1,1,2,3,4);
                                             QUERY PLAN                                              
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on fruits  (cost=0.00..217.50 rows=250 width=11) (actual time=0.023..4.358 rows=4 loops=1)
   Filter: (COALESCE(quantity, (-1)) = ANY ('{-1,1,2,3,4}'::integer[]))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 9996
 Total runtime: 4.395 ms
```

Unless a coalesce expression index is created:

```
create index fruits_coalesce_index on fruits(coalesce(quantity, -1));
analyze fruits;

explain analyze
SELECT * 
FROM fruits
WHERE COALESCE(quantity, -1) IN (-1,1,2,3,4);
                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using fruits_coalesce_index on fruits  (cost=0.00..25.34 rows=5 width=11) (actual time=0.112..0.124 rows=4 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (COALESCE(quantity, (-1)) = ANY ('{-1,1,2,3,4}'::integer[]))
 Total runtime: 0.172 ms
```

But it is still worse than the plain `or` query with a plain index on quantity.

Comment: FYI: I did the `COALESCE(quantity, x)` with a value of `x` that was in the `IN(x, 2, 3,4)` list. Your `x=0` would cause rows that have `quantity=0` to appear as well, which is different from the intended behaviour.

Comment: My Table has 500.000 rows and 25 columns of integers. But the combination of coalesce with a coalesce expression index did improve my performance significantly. I hadn't thought of that combination. Thank you very much Clodoaldo Neto and wildplasser!

Comment: @wildplasser You are right. It is corrected now. But notice that your example which coaleces to 1 is also not good since it will return those lines with quantity = 1 when there are nulls even when the quantity = 1 is not desired.

Comment: @Hartwig Corrected to coalesce to -1.

Comment: What if a row with `quantity= -1` would exist? I mean: it is not impossible or constrained in any way. The most robust way is still to map the nulls to a value in the IN-list.

Comment: @wildplasser That would break it. Did you understand why mapping the null to a value in the IN list is wrong?

Comment: No, IMO mapping to a value in the list is correct, and it produces the same results as the original `NULL OR IN()` query, even if the sentinel value happens to be present in the table, which is not the case in your method.

Answer (score 1):

Ugly hack with `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM fruits
 WHERE COALESCE(quantity,1) IN (1,2,3,4)
   ;
```

Please check the resulting plan. IIRC, the optimiser knows about `COALESCE()` in cases like this.

UPDATE: Alternative: use the `EXISTS(NOT EXISTS(NOT IN))` trick (which generates a different plan here)

```
-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM fruits fr
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM fruits ex
        WHERE ex.id = fr.id
        AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM fruits nx
                WHERE nx.id = ex.id
                AND nx.quantity NOT IN (1,2,3,4)
                )
        )
   ;
```

BTW: while testing, (upto 1 million rows, with only 4+ a few qualifying) , the first query (which does not use an index) is always faster than the second (which uses indices and hash anti-join) YMMV.

UPDATE 2: the original query `IS NULL OR IN()` is a clear winner here:

```
-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM fruits
 WHERE quantity IS NULL
    OR quantity IN (1,2,3,4)
   ;
```

Comment: I needed a way to not use OR, so that I could use an index when ~ 25 multiple columns would be used in a query. In that case a multi column index greatly speeds up the query. Many thanks for your initial input.

Comment: ~25 multiple columns: maybe should reconsider your data model. (not having a primary key is an indication) BTW: for a `quantity` column it would make perfect sense to define it as `quantity INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`

Comment: Thank you for your concern. The table above was just an illustration for the problem I was trying to solve. Of course I do use a primary key in the original table and I'm pretty sure the data model is fine. Thanks again for your time and valuable input @wildplasser.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your exact question, but you could build a partial index tailored for your query:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_partial (quantity) ON fruits
WHERE quantity IN (1,2,3,4) OR quantity IS NULL;
```

From the docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html

This index should then be used by your query and speed it up.

Comment: You are correct, but I have too many different queries so that I could use them efficiently.